# What is happening in Dream Zanarkand, and why are its inhabitants able to affect Spira?

Tags: final-fantasy

During the course of Final Fantasy X, we learn that Tidus is really from Dream Zanarkand, a dream reproduction of Zanarkand at the height of its glory.

We learn that Yu Yevon sacrificed the citizens of Zanarkand in order to create this Dream Zanarkand, and that Tidus is simply a character from this dream world.

How is it then, that Sin can bring Tidus to Spira, and pass as a completely normal person? What does this tell us about Dream Zanarkand?

We know that Tidus is blissfully unaware that his Zanarkand is simply a dream. Is it then safe to say that all inhabitants of Dream Zanarkand are unaware?

Then, if we consider Jecht for a moment. He is also a dream created by Yu Yevon. However, Yu Yevon also created Sin. Yet, Jecht, who by all accounts doesn't even exist, became a Final Aeon who defeated Sin, albeit only temporarily.

If inhabitants of Dream Zanarkand are able to impact Spira in a corporeal way, and Yu Yevon and his army of fayth are able to dream up these characters at will, why not do more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the FFX world, there doesn't seem to be any difference between real items and creatures (like machina, Wakka, chocobos, etc), and those created by pyreflies (Tidus, Sin, spheres, aeons, etc). Pyrefly versions of people stay around indefinitely unless they're "Sent" by a Summoner. Or as in the case of Tidus, the fayth that dreamed him up in the first place are Sent.

> We know that Tidus is blissfully unaware that his Zanarkand is simply
>   a dream. Is it then safe to say that all inhabitants of Dream
>   Zanarkand are unaware?

Yes. We see the same thing with Jecht's backstory, who didn't know Zanarkand was a dream either. The only one in Dream Zanarkand who knows the truth is Auron, who isn't a dream but just unsent, and is so far the only non-dream person we've seen enter Zanarkand.

> Then, if we consider Jecht for a moment. He is also a dream created by Yu Yevon. However, Yu Yevon also created Sin. Yet, Jecht, who by all accounts doesn't even exist, became a Final Aeon who defeated Sin, albeit only temporarily.

Almost, but not quite. Jecht and Tidus are not created by Yu Yevon, they are dreams given form by the fayth (souls) of the original inhabitants of Zanarkand, using pyreflies. It's not outright stated, but a safe bet to say that the Dream Zanarkand people are based on the original inhabitants of Zanarkand (see: Shuyin / Tidus in FFX-2).

> If inhabitants of Dream Zanarkand are able to impact Spira in a corporeal way, and Yu Yevon and his army of fayth are able to dream up these characters at will, why not do more?

Maybe they could, but why would they? Yu Yevon seems to have everything exactly the way he wants it. Dream Zanarkand stands in its prime, all its inhabitants will exist forever, and he's rigged a system where even if its guardian is destroyed, the destroyer will have to become the new guardian.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the plot, neither offering a canonical source nor using any other, outside of FFX gameplay (tinged with a bit of *probable* misunderstanding of the ending) and actually just one, really big comment:

---

Sir Auron facilitates this (who's he talking to, *"Are you sure?"* if not Sin). Perhaps Sin was created in order to bring people out, at the cost of being *a sin* to use such power.

This was a plan desired by Jecht-Sin, as Tidus was his son, and Sir Auron who was also a dream, to bring them into the real world (to insure not only Jecht's release from Sin, but also that it be done by one who wouldn't abuse the power they'd receive). Use of this power is left up to the judgement of the current Summoner-Sin.

Personally I don't think Jecht expected Sin to be vanquished but knew his son and old friend could play a pivotal part in a favorable outcome (of course he'd be in the stands, turn to you and say, *yea that's my kid out there*).

We can only assume that previous summoner's parties have hatched similar plans or that there are other ways to manifest people from the dream world. Many people are revealed to us throughout the plot as spirits.

Speaking of which, Yu Yevon also gave us Seymour; *that's enough, thank you.* Yevon did "do more", so much so as to give us Sin; a thing so horrible it had to be stopped.

I would speculate that anyone like Tidus, who arrives in Spira through a giant hole in the sky, is aware of *something going on*. The ones still inside *The Matrix* have no idea.